# The best way of combining two canases in p5.js using if/else

Tags: p5.js

I have two clocks and I am trying to add the ability to switch between the digital versiona nd the analog version. Currently, they sit in two different .js files. Should I combine them and use an if/else functionality to show which one is to be displayed or is there a better way to call on the other file to display it?

I am a newbie coder, so I'm very raw when it comes to coding. Go easy on me! ;)

I have attached the code below where I try to use if/else but I get an error on the else line ('Declaration or statement expected').

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YuolX.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WtxPy.png)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: You've got a syntax error.  You can only use `else` immediately after closing an `if`.  But your `if (analogVisible)` was already closed on line 54.  You can safely move all of those helper functions to outside of your `draw` function.